# Display an image before each tag in Wordpress

Tags: php, image, wordpress, tags, taxonomy

I have made custom posts with custom taxonomies. I am now trying to display an image in front of every custom tag.

With the code below I can only se an image in front of the first tag. I'd like the image to show before every tag.

```
<?php the_terms( $post->ID, 'case_tags', '<img src="theimage" />','<br /> '); ?></div><!--end .case-tags -->
```

I this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation on the_terms function-

```
<?php the_terms( $id, $taxonomy, $before, $sep, $after ); ?>
```

Looks like your providing the image as the before parameter, so i'ts only being printed once.  Try putting the image in twice, so it gets printed for both the before and the seperation parameters.

```
<?php the_terms( $post->ID, 'case_tags', '<img src="theimage" />', '<img src="theimage" />','<br /> '); ?></div><!--end .case-tags -->
```

Comment: Thank you it worked. At first my line-break became screwed up but I fixed it.

Comment: Posting the solution code in case someone else has the same problem.

    <?php the_terms( $post->ID, 'case_tags', '<img src="theimage" />','<br /><img src="theimage" />',' '); ?>